# Private Key with PHP and "openssl_pkey_get_details() expects parameter 1 to be resource"

Tags: php, openssl, key, private

I have a problem with this function

```
$priv_key = openssl_pkey_get_private(file_get_contents("server.pem"));

$keyData = openssl_pkey_get_details($priv_key);

$keyData['key'] = str_replace('-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----', '', $keyData['key']);
$keyData['key']= trim(str_replace('-----END PRIVATE KEY-----','',$keyData['key']));

echo $keyData['key'];
```

It should return the private key but it gives me this error

> Warning: openssl_pkey_get_details() expects parameter 1 to be
>   resource, boolean given in
>   C:\Users\User\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\chiaveP.php on line 14

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: If you were to `echo file_get_contents("server.pem");` does it show what you would expect?

Comment: It should show the entire file contents server.pem
then take the private key .. but it does not work

Comment: server.pem 
It is in the same folder as the php file and with error_reporting return 
the same error Warning: openssl_pkey_get_details() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Users\User\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\chiaveP.php on line 14

Comment: [openssl_pkey_get_details() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16287500), [openssl_pkey_export and "cannot get key from parameter 1"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17272809), [openssl_free_key expects parameter 1 to be resource](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17726342), ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure from your comment whether trying to echo the contents of the `server.pem` file failed or if you meant the whole script. Hopefully the code below will help identify where the issue(s) is/are!

```
<?php

    $debug=true;
    $cert='/full/path/to/server.pem';/* this should be outside the document root */
    $keytype='PRIVATE KEY';/* this is here because in testing I have an `RSA PRIVATE KEY` */


    if( realpath( $cert ) ){
        /* The file exists at the path given: read the contents */

        $priv_key = openssl_pkey_get_private( file_get_contents( realpath( $cert ) ) );

        if( $priv_key ) {

            $keyData = openssl_pkey_get_details( $priv_key );

            $keyData['key'] = str_replace( '-----BEGIN '.$keytype.'-----', '', $keyData['key'] );
            $keyData['key'] = trim( str_replace( '-----END '.$keytype.'-----','',$keyData['key'] ) );   

            echo $keyData['key'];   
        } else {
            echo $debug ? 'failed to read private key' : 'error #1';
        }
    } else {
        echo $debug ? 'unable to find ' . $cert : 'error #2';   
    }

?>
```

As a possible alternative, as you say that the `.pem` file is in the same directory as the php script, perhaps try:

```
$data=file_get_contents(realpath(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'server.pem'));
echo $debug ? $data : '';
$priv_key = openssl_pkey_get_private( $data );

/*
    I tried using the path ( `c:/wwwroot/certificates/server.pem` ) as the parameter to the
    `openssl_pkey_get_private` rather than actually reading the contents into a string 
    but that failed. The method above however worked for me when the cert was in the same dir.
*/
```

Comment: at this point it is that the private key file is not good ? I 've created with the command genrsa -des3 -out server.pem
1024
openssl on the terminal

Comment: It took me quite a while to get the various aspects correct when trying to generate certificates - and I'm not 100% sure they are perfect yet. One of the tricky bits I found was getting the config file (`openssl.cnf`) setup correctly and locatable by the php scripts ( on windows by setting the correct environment variable and path ) and accessible to apache

Comment: It returns the private key and  print in Browser... thank you very much... thank youuuuuu

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting an error on `openssl_pkey_get_private()` as it is clearly returning a boolean false. From the docs:

> Returns a positive key resource identifier on success, or FALSE on error.

It's a good idea to put a check in place when methods return false on error as it makes your code easier to debug.